# All answers down voted in a question?

Tags: support, down-votes

It seems (to me) that all answers to the following post got down voted few minutes back

[What does `return 0x1;` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904219/what-does-return-0x1-means)

I understand that an answer may be down voted if it is incorrect, but it is hard to believe that all answers, including the accepted one, are incorrect.

What might be going on?

Comment: indeed suspicious, see the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3904219/timeline), maybe the OP didn't understand how to indicate the answers didn't help him

Comment: @Tobias: Thanks, thanks for the timeline link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They in fact all have a downvote. Impossible to tell why.

It probably was a random act of "vandalism", or somebody was pissed off about receiving negative feedback to their answer, or somebody genuinely thinking the answers were all wrong.

There is no possibility to find out who did the voting though, not even for 10k+ users or moderators, so it's all speculation.

I would ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After this thread was opened, someone probably up-voted all the answers. State restored :-).

Comment: Not even for moderators? I thought moderators can see who voted on what?

Comment: @sepp I can be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure only the developers can see that

Comment: @sepp2k No we cannot. We have a limited view of voting to track voting anomalies but we have no way of knowing who voted on what question. The Dev Team does have access as far as I am aware.

Comment: Yes, in an earlier question about the Electorate badge, it was confirmed that everyone's voting history is stored and simply not made public.